# Check and return missing values from an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am working in a laravel project. I've an array named **$headings** like this-

```
  0 => array:1 [
    0 => array:5 [
      0 => "name"
      1 => "phone_number"
      2 => "department"
      3 => "division"
      4 => "status"
    ]
  ]
]
```

And I've another sample array named **$sample_data** like this-

```
array:3 [
  0 => "name"
  1 => "email"
  2 => "meta_data"
]
```

How can I get the missing values of **$sample_data** in **$headings** array & get output for this example like this-
 `$result=['email', 'meta_data']`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why is this tagged with Laravel without sharing any related code?

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$headings = [
    0 => "name",
    1 => "phone_number",
    2 => "department",
    3 => "division",
    4 => "status"
];

$sample_data = [
  0 => "name",
  1 => "email",
  2 => "meta_data"
];

$difference = array_diff($headings, $sample_data);
print_r($difference);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => phone_number
    [2] => department
    [3] => division
    [4] => status
)
```

Comment: I like this better. As it uses core PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Laravel` Collections, with the `diff()` method, that compares arrays. You have to wrap everything in Collections, to achieve this. You can find the `diff()` [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-diff).

```
$headings = collect($headings[0]); // unpack it from the first array it is wrapped in
$sampleData = collect($sampleData);

$diff = $headings->diff($sampleData);

// should be ['phone_number', 'department', 'division', 'status']
$diff->all();
```